# Theme Dev | Convert Template to Theme

Tags: themes, templates, customization

What is the solution in theme development for section in [this template Home Page](http://demo.thedevelovers.com/business/repute-v1.2.1/) so user can edit from admin panel.

1. "Main Features" Section, at bottom of slider, it says "Strong Structure", "Global English", "Dynamic Change", "Exponential Growth"
2. "The Boxed Content" Section, has "Goal Oriented" and 3 More...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want a widget to control content dynamically from the admin panel, then you can use the [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin by Elliot Condon to create custom dynamic content and retrieve it every place all over the website. After installing the plugin, simply create fields in the plugin page and get the content in every HTML tag you want. Like this:

```
<?php the_field( 'Your Custom Field Name' ); ?>
```

You can see a real example and full documentation on the [ACF website](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/displaying-custom-field-values-in-your-theme/).

Comment: Yes, that's what i mean, ok i will try it, thank you for your answer :-)

Comment: If the answer works for you, the best thank you is to accept it (click the check mark under the vote arrows on the left), and once you have enough reputation, you can also vote up answers that are helpful.

Comment: Do not use ACF as an alternative. It is quite crappy to remove it later on